# Do IT departments keep track of your wifi activity?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address

I connect my phone to my office wifi. All our visitors have access to it. A few days back, when I was on my lunch break (outside office building) I opened a porn site on my phone. After browsing for a while I realized I was still on the office wifi. Does the IT department generally keep track of all wifi activity by mac address?

Comment: I think this is as much a "culture" as a technology question.Discounting the fact that you're casually browsing porn over lunch - what does your AUP say? Are your admins bored enough to report you to HR over a single porn site opening? What happens if someone shouldersurfs your porn - will they get offended or ask you for recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the IT department generally keep track of all wifi activity by mac address?

Generally: No.

Technically it is not hard to track to which sites you connect. If you view webpages (rather than say use SSH, imap, RDP, ...) then it is also likely that everything is logged in a local proxy.   The goal of that is not to track you, but to add a place for scanning for malware and to reduce traffic to the Internet.

So, yes, there are likely logs.

However there should not be anyone viewing those logs unless they have a good reason. E.g. trouble shooting network connections, or tracking an employee who has given serious reasons and only when management has approved of it. (Often requiring classic dead tree paper and signatures of that employees manager and IT manager).

So, relax. You are almost certainly not in trouble.

---

Having said that; it is a very good idea to keep personal devices off the company net. Many firms even provide two networks; work and guest. If you are on a personal Internet connection or on guest then they really have nothing to complain about.

(All of which is ignoring if a company even should object what you do in your own free time (or on break), outside office premises. Though that may vary per culture).

Answer (score 1):

If you realy want to know, you will have to check the law of your country. In most countries your company would need to have notified you that they do this. If your company is big enough to be hosting their own DNS servers, it is relatively easy to set up, so they might have it. Yet, if it is not common public knowledge that they do this kind of tracking, I'm sure they would only expose they do this in very serious instances of abuse.